# Rails: Public_Activity Gem - uninitialised constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, public-activity

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I have installed the public_activity gem.

I followed the Ryan Bates Railscast and took the controller based approach, and also the lighter Common option (as opposed to tracking the Model).

In my activities_controller I have:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
  end
end
```

In my project.rb, I have:

```
include PublicActivity::Common
```

In my projects controller, create action, I have:

```
@project.create_activity :create, owner: current_user
```

In my activity view - index, I have:

```
<% Activities.each do |activity| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="indexdisplay">

            <span class="indexheading"> 
              <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %>
            </span>
            <span class="indexsubtext">                 
              <%= render_activity activity %>
            </span>
```

In my public activity (view folder)/project/_create.html.erb, I have:

```
<% if activity.trackable %>
  <%= link_to activity.trackable.name, activity.trackable %>
<% else %>
  which has since been removed
<% end %>
```

When I try this, I get this error:

```
NameError at /activities
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Activities
```

I tried replacing the opening line of the activity#index so that Activities, is Activity, but it just changed the error message to:

```
NameError at /activities
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Activities
```

What does this error mean? How do I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you use Class in your loop. Try to use your instance variable in your controller.

Change this

```
<% Activities.each do |activity| %>
```

into

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<% Activity.find_each do |activity| %>`

1. Model name always is singular
2. You cannot call `each` just on Model
3. I'd recommend you use `find_each` instead of `each` in case you have a lot of records
4. if you do want all the records you can always use `.all` method

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each